# Validación de dominio Express

Tags: express

necesito validar solo correos con el dominio de "email@mi.email.validacion.mx", pero soy nuevo en express, solo tengo en la validacion esto:

```
check('email').isEmail().not().isEmpty()
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares, puedes encontrar varias maneras en este foro o en otros, hay infinidad de validaciones, pero te dejo una:

```
const regularExpression= /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

const emailPrueba = "pruebadeEmail@a.com"

console.log(regularExpression.test(emailPrueba));
```

El output sería en boolean:

```
// output:
true
```

En caso de no ser correcto:

```
// output:
false
```

> Hay otras formas si gustas como el paquete de `express-validator` que al parecer ya estás usando, de lo contrario puedes indicarme y te coloco un ejemplo.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456065/how-to-format-and-validate-email-node-js

Comment: Si, estoy trabajando con express-validator, si me puedes dar un ejemplo estaría encantado la verdad, es que no logro que valide solo un dominio especifico